# Power BI: Losing precision by using SUMMARIZECOLUMN?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI and I am making a matrix for Sales value. As we use various currencies and convert the numbers, each Sales number can have as many as 15 decimal points. NumericColumn corresponds to Sales going forward.

There is this OriginalTable:

```
NumericColumn,
OtherColumn1,
... ,
OtherColumnN
```

This OriginalTable is imported from SQL Server and has ~ 400K rows. NumericColumn has type numeric(35,15).

As there are a lot of unimportant columns in OriginalTable I made a new table in the following manner where *M* << *N*:

```
NewTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
OriginalTable[NumericColumn],
OriginalTable[OtherColumn1],
... , 
OriginalTable[OtherColumnM]
)
```

The sum of the "NumericColumn" in OriginalTable is 2,550,8**32.98** . This number is seen by putting "NumericColumn" in Value field as Sum and without setting any Rows or Columns in Visualization -> Matrix.

On the other hand, the sum of the "NumericColumn" in NewTable is 2,550,8**29.14** (3.84 smaller than that in OriginalTable).

It seems that I lost precision when I created a new table. Would somebody kindly take a look? Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks & Regards,

Kyoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the M query transformation keeps up to 8 decimal points when you are importing data and applying Change Type. As you said you have up to 15 decimal points, you can try the below steps and check it worked for you or not.

Come back to report clicking **Cloase & Apply** button. Now in the report, select your decimal value column configure the column Format and Decimal points as shown below-

[image]

Now applying SUMMARIZECOLUMNS should give your expected result.

Comment: Hi R_R. Thank you very much for your prompt response. It looks like my version of Power BI Desktop is different from yours and I am still trying to figure out the corresponding button. Just wanted to thank you first. Will let you know how it went.

Comment: I am using Power BI Desktop version 2.69. My NumericColumn is automatically recognized as Decimal number data type and Format is Decimal number with decimal points setting "Auto". I am afraid changing decimal point setting in Formatting did not change the results. I still get the correct double precision calculation result for the OriginalTable but a bit off calculation result for the NewTable created with SUMMARIZECOLUMNS. I tried this starting from scratch (i.e., new empty pbix file, importing data, etc.). Has anyone created new table containing double-precision columns? R_R any idea?

Comment: Change it auto to 15 decimal point. Just check it R&D basis.

Comment: R_R. Thanks. You are right. I am sorry I did not tell that I tried your suggestions. After importing data, I changed OriginalTable's NumericColumn decimal precision from auto to 15. Then created NewTable using SUMMARIZECOLUMNS. Then OriginalTable shows 2,550,832.976907979200000 and NewTable still shows 2,550,982.46 in each Matrix visual. I must be missing something.

Comment: You can provide me a report with small amount of data with issue. I can check.

Comment: Hi R_R. Now I know what I did wrong. I was not including all the primary keys in the OriginalTable when I created NewTable with SUMMERIZECOLUMNS. It was not rounding issue or anything but my mistake. This behavior can be easily replicated with  OriginalTable being (Column1, Column2) = ((1, 7), (2, 7), (2, 7)). OriginalTable sum gives 21 but NewTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Column1, Column2) gives 14 removing the duplicate row. My OriginalTable has dozens of primary keys and I forgot to include one of them. And I got a slightly off number. Thank you very much for your time R_R! I appreciate it!

Comment: Nice to see you got your solution :)